# JavaScript AngularJS Issue with objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I've been running in a problem that I simply don't understand.
I have a $rootScope object, user, so `$rootScope.user`.
Within this object, I have an array, missions, so `$rootScope.user.missions`.

When I do `console.log($rootScope.user)` I get this (which is correct, I currently have 1 mission)

[image]

But if I do `console.log($rootScope.user.missions)` on the next line, I get nothing (not undefined, just nothing),
and if I do `console.log($rootScope.user.missions.length)`, I `return 0` (as if I don't have any mission).

Does someone have any idea what's happening exactly?

EDIT: Here a screenshot of what `console.log($rootScope.user)` return
[image]
On line 3390, I run `console.log($rootScope.user.missions)`

EDIT: On the first line, I do `console.log($rootScope.user.missions)`, and on the second line `console.log($rootScope.user.missions.length)`.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yhun.png)

Comment: Can you show us when you use console.log(...) ? And when are the items added to the array ?